# why is (int) required in return (int) java.lang.Math.round?

Tags: java, return-type

I wrote

```
return java.lang.Math.round(someVariable*1.234234);
```

into eclipse in a function which returns an int but it wanted me to include (int) to make it like this

```
 return (int) java.lang.Math.round
```

What is this (int) doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you look at the Docs,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

`Math.round` returns a long when it's parameter isn't a float.

So you have to cast the long to an int.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for the Edit, I just realized my small error and was about to fix it :p

Comment: Also, be careful with casting to int, it might overflow for big numbers. Maybe better to change the return type of the method to long (depends on your usage, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The `Math.round` invoked with a `double` returns a `long`. It is there to cast the `long` result to `int` type...

Answer (score 0):

It is [***casting***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) the returned variable's data type which is a `long` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

round has 2 overloads,

long    round(double a);

and

int     round(float a);

since the const you wrote is a double, you need to cast it to float.
try:

```
return java.lang.Math.round(someVariable*1.234234f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the result of the function `java.lang.Math.round(double a)` which is a `long` in a function that needs an `int`.
So you have to change the return type in your function prototype from `int` to `long`

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by prototype? I don't think I've ever heard somebody use that term with Java before :O

Comment: the function signature, how do you call the declaration of a function..?

Answer (score 0):

The `Math.round(double a)` method returns a `long` which is a larger type than `int`. Therefore your action could result in a loss of information. You need to tell the compiler explicitly, with the help of a cast, that you are aware of that.